# How to scrape data ignoring embedded tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

```
<div class="seperate">
    <h2>Public info</h2>
    <p>
        <strong>Property type:</strong> Semi-detached house |
        <strong>Tenure:</strong> Leasehold |
        <strong>Last sale:</strong> £71,000 | <strong>Sale date:</strong> 5th Dec 2007 - <a href="" class="toggle_sold_prices">Previous sales</a>
        <span id="sold-prices" class="none">
                        <br>
                            <strong>Property type:</strong>
                            Semi-detached house | 
                            <strong>Tenure:</strong>
                            Leasehold | 
                        <strong>Previous sale:</strong> £75,000 | 
                        <strong>Sale date:</strong> 
     3rd Oct 2006
                        <br>
                            <strong>Property type:</strong>
                            Semi-detached house | 
                            <strong>Tenure:</strong>
                            Leasehold | 
                        <strong>Previous sale:</strong> £36,000 | 
                        <strong>Sale date:</strong> 
    26th Sep 2002
                        <br>
                            <strong>Property type:</strong>
                            Semi-detached house | 
                            <strong>Tenure:</strong>
                            Leasehold | 
                        <strong>Previous sale:</strong> £39,950 | 
                        <strong>Sale date:</strong> 
    27th Jan 1995
                            <span class="new-build">New build</span>
        </span>
        | <a href="/for-sale/details/42175871"><i class="icon icon-home nolink"></i>Currently for sale</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

I am trying to scrape the data for "Last Sale" , "Sale Date" and "Currently for sale" values, except everything inside

```
<span id="sold-prices" class="none">
```

I know that I can do

```
html.search(".//div[@class='separate']")
```

to get the HTML inside the separate div, but I do not know how I can scrape the data for the tags I want. Any ideas?

Comment: how about just take data between `<strong>Last sale:</strong>` and ` | ` ?   `nokogiri` will not help, You need experience of using string manipulation tools.

Comment: @num8er, let me give it a try and post an update

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". When asking, we need you to reduce your input to the bare minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem and show a more substantial attempt at solving the problem. That helps us avoid duplicating your attempt or wasting time refining the input to match the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Nokogiri finishes processing the HTML it's really easy to find and manipulate nodes. Sometimes that means selectively removing nodes to simplify the DOM. This is one of those times:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<div class="seperate">
  <p>
    <strong>Property type:</strong> Semi-detached house |
    <strong>Tenure:</strong> Leasehold |
    <strong>Last sale:</strong> £71,000 | <strong>Sale date:</strong> 5th Dec 2007 - <a href="" class="toggle_sold_prices">Previous sales</a>
    <span id="sold-prices" class="none">
      <br>
          <strong>Property type:</strong>
          Semi-detached house | 
          <strong>Tenure:</strong>
          Leasehold | 
    </span>
  </p>
</div>
EOT

doc.at('#sold-prices').remove
data = doc.search('strong').map{ |strong|
    [strong.text, strong.next_sibling.text.tr('|', '').strip]
}.to_h

data # => {"Property type:"=>"Semi-detached house", "Tenure:"=>"Leasehold", "Last sale:"=>"£71,000", "Sale date:"=>"5th Dec 2007 -"}
```

The trick is:

```
doc.at('#sold-prices').remove
```

which gets rid of the forest so you can see the trees you want.

There's a tiny bit more needed to clean up the resulting data, but the rest of the code should be self-explanatory so tweaking it should be easy for you.